# rgb2lab discrepancy opencv and matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4.3, I used this function:

```
cvtColor(img,CV_BGRtoLab)
```

I have also tried `CV_LBGRtoLab`, and I have compared it to a similar function in matlab.

```
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_he = applycform(image, cform);
```

They are giving different images.

Apparently some post tell me that the white point illuminant used by them are different. I need them to be matching, I am planning to implement it myself. Is there any implementation in c++ which I can refer to?

Comment: Have you looked at this bug: http://code.opencv.org/issues/1511
- it appears to be related...

Comment: Thank you,but i want an implementation from rgb to lab space.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to function `rgb2lab(int R, int G, int B, int []lab)` in [this page](http://www.f4.fhtw-berlin.de/~barthel/ImageJ/ColorInspector//HTMLHelp/farbraumJava.htm). The idea is first convert to `XYZ` and then to `lab`. It also contains conversions between other color spaces.